# Is there a way to rotate the x-axis labels in the visreg package?

Tags: r, graphics, label, axis, visreg

*** EDIT **** Figured it out: `scales = list(rot = 90)`

I am using the visreg() function to plot a linear model comparing bird weights between years. I have three different species, so the graph is very crowded. I want to rotate the x-axis labels so they are perpendicular, but I cannot figure out how to do it. I have used `las = 2` in numerous locations, to no avail. Help would be appreciated! Thank you.

```
 visreg(hawk_lm1, xvar = "Year", by = "Species", whitespace = 0.4, las = 2,
       points.par = list(cex = 0.5, col = "grey"))
```

[A screenshot of the graph as it is at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3xB5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of the visreg package, if you use the  `by=` argument the plot is made using the lattice package. In Lattice you can use the `scales=` argument alongside `rot()` to rotate the axis, just include the parameter in the visreg function as an additional argument and it should do the job. I created this example from the airquality dataset to illustrate.

```
library(visreg)
airquality$Heat <- cut(airquality$Temp, 3, labels=c("Cool", "Mild", "Hot"))
fit <- lm(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Heat, data=airquality)

##default  x axis labels
visreg(fit, "Wind", by="Heat",  bty="n", ylab="Ozone")

##rotated x  axis labels
visreg(fit, "Wind", by="Heat",  bty="n", ylab="Ozone", scales=list(x=list(rot=90)))
```